# Error Propagation (complicated case)

Tags: numerical-methods, error-function, error-propagation

I have a function:

$$G=\frac{(\frac{4\pi^2}{T^2}+\frac{1}{\tau^2})\cdot r^2 \cdot d\cdot S}{4M\cdot L}$$

and I need to do error propagation on this function:

$$\delta G=\sqrt{(\frac{\partial G}{\partial \tau}\delta \tau)^2+(\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}\delta r)^2+(\frac{\partial G}{\partial d}\delta d)^2+(\frac{\partial G}{\partial L}\delta L)^2+(\frac{\partial G}{\partial S}\delta S)^2+(\frac{\partial G}{\partial M}\delta M)^2+(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\delta T)^2}$$

If by looking at this you already have a headache...Yeah, I'm already dying. So I know how to do this for simpler functions like

$$f(m,v)=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$\delta f=\sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}\delta m)^2(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\delta v)^2}$$

Where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}=\frac{1}{2}v^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=mv$...Or cases for addition.

But the giant thing I have here where there is adition, multiplication, and powers, i'm just lost. How would the idividual term look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithmic differentiation is your friend
$$G=\frac{\left(\frac{4 \pi ^2}{T^2}+\frac{1}{\tau^2}\right)\, r^2 \, d\, S}{4M\, L}=\frac{\left(\frac{4 \pi ^2 \tau ^2}{T^2}+1\right)\,  d\, S}{4M\, L}$$
$$\log(G)=\log\left(\frac{4 \pi ^2 \tau ^2}{T^2}+1\right)+\log(d)+\log(S)-\log(M)-\log(L)-\log(4)$$
Differentiate to obtain, for any variable $X$,$$\frac1 G\frac{\partial G}{\partial X}=\text{something}$$ and, when done,use
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial X}=G \times\text{something}$$

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this, then i wanted to ask for $log(G)=log(\frac{4pi^2 \tau^2}{T^2}+1)$ We have two variables to differentiate $(\tau , T)$, how. should that go?

Comment: Do i differentiate $log(\frac{4pi^2\tau^2}{T^2})$ twice considering each variable as a constant each time?

Comment: Sorry would you be so kind to wirte one term down like how the differentiation would look like, im really confused now....I usually use the simplified version, but i was told i wasnt allowed to do so this time

Comment: Its ok i figured out